# FlowlayoutPanel not displaying all it's child control

Tags: flowlayoutpanel

I am having a flowlayoutpanel which is having multiple child control panel . Child panels are being added dynamically . There is one trackbar which provide the functionality to resize the child panels ( with background image). While resizing the child panels flowlayoutpanel is not able to display all the child panels and it's display empty spaces in the bottom . Looking for help thanks in advance.